# Java spring Multiple microservice with keycloack

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to build microservice architecture like in the image. The question is how do I must authenticate users in resource service using keycloack. Do I must to get the token from UI app and add this token manually in the app or there is some automatic method using spring app to get info from the resource service?
[image]

If I need to add it manually then how can I get this token inside the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak provides spring security integration module. It renders login form for  your UI application that authenticates user against keycloak. The token is stored then in session. Keycloak plugin is responsible to validate the token against keycloak server.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.adoc